# Accessing Relationship Table data in sqlalchemy with API

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have the following association table defined in my postgres database.

```
student_tests_association_table =db.Table('student_tests',
                    db.Column('students_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('students.id')),
                    db.Column('tests_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tests.id'))
```

and I want to add these non-foreign keys to the table so that I can access the scores from a particular test taken by a particular student.

```
                    db.Column('MathNC_Score', db.Integer),
                    db.Column('MathC_Score', db.Integer),
                    db.Column('Reading_Score', db.Integer),
                    db.Column('Writing_Score', db.Integer)))
```

If I did this, how would I access the data above? 
For example, if I defined a function to be:

```
def get_score(subject):
        return student_tests_association_table.c.[subject]
```

it would be accessing the whole column, so if I wanted to just get one score, i.e 'MathC_Score', for test_id = 1, how would it look?

Also if I wanted to add all of the scores for one test, would the function look something like...

```
 def get_total_score():
        for c in student_tests_association_table:
            if c.key == 'students_id' or 'tests_id':
                pass 
            else: 
                sum = sum + c 
            return sum
```

Edit: Afterthought
Or would it make more sense to have the scores be included in the Test database model? But since for each student having a unique score for each Test, it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I think your question boils down to query syntax, what are you using to connect to the database? You can either use raw sql or a database abstraction layer. Are you using something like that?

Comment: are you structuring the database or accessing with this query? based on this question & existing code, you've got a test table with it's own id etc where the subjects live. if that's the case you shouldn't be adding those columns to your key table rather create a separate Table to get access.

Comment: I am using sqlalchemy for querying @c8999c3f964f64

Comment: @brddawg The student would take a test, and I would like to store the score for the test subjects. I thought I could just add these columns to the already associated table of student_tests so that the other columns aligned with the student and test taken have the scores listed next to them to access. Do I have to add the score fields to a db model?

Comment: unrelated to the sqlalchemy query, your database will be more efficient if you 'normalize' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoTyrdT9SZI and remove the student and test information and hold those in separate tables. in this situation you'd have a tables containing: 1.  students_is & name, 2. student_tests as you have it in your question, and 3. test_id & test. in your query you'd join the student to the student_tests to the test, input a student id and maybe a subject and get all tests related. Related to your edit, you could add a column to the current structure with score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is remove the columns [MathNC_Score, MathC_Score,  Reading_Score, etc..] and use a *subject* column, then have the score in a separate "score" column. This way you can

```
query = student_tests.select()\
    .with_only_colums(student_tests.c.score)\
    .where(student_test.c.students_id == X)\
    .where(student_test.c.subject == "MathNC")
```

to get all the MathNC test scores of this student. Otherwise you'll end up with a bunch of empty fields and have to go through the effort of checking which column actually has a value in it, instead of querying for it directly. The *subject* field would contain a string, and the *score* your int / float

The "with_only_columns" method removes all columns in your results which arent listed as arguments, so you dont need to loop through and exclude them manually in your loop when summing up the scores

---- EDIT

If you want to serialize the results of the query you can turn everything into strings and return that. (Not a very sophisticated approach, but its easy)

```
my_session = Session(engine)
result = my_session.execute(query)
return_dict = dict() 
for row in result: 
    for key, value in row.items():
        return_dict.update({key: str(value)})
return return_dict
```

Comment: Thank you^^ this helps alot, but if I want to access this in an API way, how do I get the query with select to ouptut the score data in a json format?

Comment: I'll add another answer but you should generally ask a new question instead of using a comment

Comment: Ahh okay thank you, still new to this. so I'll mark the above answer as correct.